# HighCharts - round the mean value on bellcurve

Tags: charts, highcharts, bell-curve

How can I display only 3 digits after comma on the bell curve for both mean and standard deviation? On the chart itself.

This is what I have done. It works for the standard deviation but not for the mean. I couldn't figure out the issue.

```js
tooltip: {
shared: true,
useHTML: true,
headerFormat: '<table><tr><th colspan="2">MEAN</th></tr>',
pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color: {series.color}">{series.name} </td>' +
'<td style="text-align: right"><b>{point.x} </b></td></tr>',
footerFormat: '</table>',
valueDecimals: 3
},
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{point.x}` with numeric formatting in `pointFormat`, for example `{point.x:.3f}`.

```
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color: {series.color}">{series.name} </td>' +
      '<td style="text-align: right"><b>{point.x:.3f} </b></td></tr>',
    ...
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5cmpwkzy/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormat